# Como desinstalar R no linux?

Tags: r, linux

Estou tentando desinstalar o R da minha máquina. Como utilizo linux, utilizei o comando `sudo apt-get remove r-base` e a operação foi concluida com sucesso. Mas após dar o comando R no terminal o interpretador do R continua iniciando normalmente, como se ainda estivesse instalado na máquina. Como posso **desinstalar completamente** o R da minha máquina linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar `sudo apt-get remove r-base-core`

Caso saiba inglês aqui está a resposta mais a fundo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336644/completely-uninstall-r-linux

Answer (score -3):

Camarada Adler Soster, você consegue eliminar o R, de uma vez, entrando no Ubuntu Software e elimando o R por ele. Somente isto.